# JWT for ASP .NET Core - Unique secret key for each user

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have ASP .NET Core application. I want use JWT for auth. There is `AddJwtBearer` method which is called from `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`. This method initialize `IssuerSigningKey` once on start. I want to have different `secretKeys` for each user. I think about creating custom authorize attribute. Maybe someone already solve the similar issue.

```
.AddJwtBearer(jwtSchemeName, jwtBearerOptions => {
            jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = "secretKey",
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "ValidIssuer",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "ValidAudience ",
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
            };
        });
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: SecretKey can be broken or declassified.

Comment: It could be broken or "declassified" for each user too... In any case, you can do this by creating an HTTP Filter that intercepts the JWT authentication mechanism.

Comment: If secret key for one user has broken it will not affect other users. Also sometimes we can regenerate secretKey. @HereticMonkey

Comment: I have a similar question but about rotating the keys rather than per user. But, the AssJwtBearer seems to act as a singleton and I've not found a way to change the IssuerSigningKey after instantiation.